# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: user.id

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I get an error when I try to add data to the database. I've set up the data base and it's application

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120),nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(70),primary_key=True,nullable = False)
    post = db.Column(db.String(10000),default ="")
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.id},{self.name},{self.email},{self.post},{self.date_created}'
```

And I get issues whenever I try to create the database in the code below:

```
@app.route('/sign_up',methods = ["POST","GET"])
def sign_up():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        first_name = request.form.get('first_name')
        password_1 = request.form.get('password')
        password_2 = request.form.get('password-2')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        if user:
            flash("Email aleady exists", category = 'error')
        elif len(email) < 5:
            flash("Email name must be greater than 5 characters", category='error')
        # We'll come back to you tomorrow (i.e 25th March)
        elif len(first_name) < 2:
            flash("First Name too short",category='error')
        elif password_1 != password_2:
            flash("Make sure you typed the password correctly",category='error')
        elif len(password_1) < 8:
            flash("Make sure your password as at least 8 characters", category='error')
        else:
            new_user = User(name= first_name,email = email)
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Account Created",category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))

    return render_template("sign-up.html")
```

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: user.id
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (name, email, post, date_created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('test', 'presidentdavid@gmail.com', '', '2021-04-06 20:10:03.191785')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj). The error I get

Comment: Show the traceback as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment. Show the code that caused the traceback (properly formatted in the question). Don't just talk about "issues". What happens, what should happen?

Comment: Sorry... Lol... This is my first question still getting the hang of it... Would try to edit it back

Answer (score 0):

Update table in Postgresql. make the ID **auto increment**.

or supply the id with data ( deprecated )

Comment: Thanks.. I tried autoincrement.. It didn't work.. And I don't quite understand supplying the Id with data